# How to change display value in parameter selection pentaho reports

Tags: pentaho

I need to display "All" when my data in parameter list is -1.
Just to display in the parameter selection.

Help me with this

Thanks,
Keerthi KS

Comment: Not clear. You want your drop down to display 'All' Value? Whats the DB you use? Currently how you show the other values in your drop down or selection?

Comment: i have requirement where it should fetch data for some of the productids (43,44,45). By default it should fetch for all 3 values or we can select productids from dropdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your sql like these.

Eg:-

```
SELECT "ALL" AS column_name
UNION
SELECT column_name FROM table_name
```

in that bottom sql is your 43,44,45 sql.

If you modified like these.

Again little bit changes required in that main sql. Meaining in sql where condition.

I think your problem will be solved.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a JDBC connection, you can use a simple query like this. (I used Postgres)

```
SELECT 1 AS no,
'All' AS pid
UNION 
SELECT  2 AS no,
 '43' AS pid
UNION 
SELECT  2 AS no,
 '44' AS pid
UNION 
SELECT  2 AS no,
 '45' AS pid
order by no
```

Or if not you can use `Table` option available under Data sets in PRD. There you can hardcode the same as a table as I did above.

After that go open you parameter in PRD and in default value field type `All` and configure the Propt section in order to get data from the Data set we created.

If you fetch data from a DB you can write a Case statement, 
this is an example if you use ktr. You can include this in your query.

```
(productids IN (SELECT CASE WHEN('${paramproductid}' = 'All' OR '${paramproductid}' IS NULL) THEN productids ELSE '${paramproductid}'  END))
```

Assumptions made due to the less information in your question.